# Get notified in the background when app's "location" and "background app refresh" permissions change

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, background-process, nsnotificationcenter, user-permissions

Does anyone know if an app can get notified in the background by the system when app permissions change? I'm especially interested in getting notified when a user changes the "location" permission and the "background app refresh" permission.

So far I have looked into this call-back method:

```
locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
```

However, the app doesn't get notified in the background.

I also tried adding an observer for this notification:

```
UIApplicationBackgroundRefreshStatusDidChangeNotification
```

But I can't get it to work either.

Here's my code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {        
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "checkBackgroundPermission", name: UIApplicationBackgroundRefreshStatusDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false

    if(locationManager.respondsToSelector("requestAlwaysAuthorization")) {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }

    if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] != nil {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false

        let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let uuidString = prefs.stringForKey("UUID") as String!
        let uuid : NSUUID? = NSUUID(UUIDString: uuidString as String)

        beaconRegionGeneral = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: uuidString), identifier: "general")

        locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegionGeneral)
        setIsRanging(true)
    }


    if(application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:")) {
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(
            UIUserNotificationSettings(
                forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                categories: nil
            )
        )
    }

    return true
}

func checkBackgroundPermission() {
    sendLocalNotificationWithMessage("checkBackgroundPermission", playSound: false)
    println("checkBackgroundPermission")
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    sendLocalNotificationWithMessage("didChangeAuthorizationStatus", playSound: true)
    println("didChangeAuthorizationStatus")
}
```

Comment: Your app will be killed when the permissions change. Check the permission each time your app starts.

Comment: If the app gets killed when the permissions change, is there a way to take advantage of that? Such as checking the permissions in the applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) method?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the permissions are not yet changed when `applicationWillTerminate` is called. The app will see the new settings when it starts again.

Comment: when app gets killed, you do not get control over the code. all you can do is, check the status in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions when the application launches next time. But I am sure that, app will not crash when you change the location permissions for the app.

Comment: Thanks for the help, rmaddy, but I need to know that a permission has been changed as soon as it happens. I am hoping this is is possible.

Answer (score 1):

you can use below delegate method (from CLLocationManagerDelegate Protocol) to get notifications.

```
 optional func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
```